# no sdk path for flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

flutter doesn't run the app and asked for put --stracktrac or --debug and also didn't work and when open project structure i found this and when choose src/flutter as flutter sdk path it tell me not valid
please what should i do
[the error in project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXBNC.png)

[the output when run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41AvN.jpg)

[flutter sdk path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZzue.png)

Comment: You need to set the Android SDK path in the first image, not Flutter SDK path.

Comment: @Mobina thanks i changed it but the scond screenshot of running is stall appear, i put.       --stracktrac and tried --debug also but no change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete completely android studio + .config in C:\ and reinstall android studio and let that to download requirements .it probably should solve your problem.